# Install php-mssql in CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, centos, php5, centos6

I have a server running CentOS 6.2 with Plesk 10.4. When I SSH in, and try and install ms-sql extension it says "No package php-mssql available."

I can't seem to find much on Google for this, and I am a bit of a Linux noob. Can anyone offer any help?

EDIT: I tried installing it using "yum install php-mssql"

Comment: How did you "try and install ms-sql extension"?

Comment: "yum install php-mssql"

Answer (score 4):

`php-mssql` is in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: How would I install EPEL in CentOS 6.2? "If you are running an EL6 version ,please visit here to get the newest 'epel-release' package for EL6: The newest version of 'epel-release' for EL6" How would I know if I am running EL6?

Comment: It goes by the major number of the distro version. Hence, CentOS 6.2 is EL6.

Comment: OK thanks, will try. This linked helped for others finding this: http://gembuls.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/how-to-install-epel-repository-on-centos/

Answer (score 1):

Try this steps.

1> Install EPEL repo

```
 rpm -ivh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
```

2> 
  yum install php-mssql

Answer (score 1):

You need to install php-mssql extension on Linux CentOS6

Step 1: Install needed respositories

> rpm -Uvh
> http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
>
> rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

Step 2: Install the extension

> yum install php-mssql

Comment: Remi's repo is a tricky proposition for run-of-the-mill CentOS. Since the OP is running Plesk, all bets are off, though.

Answer (score 1):

Plesk heavily alters the distribution, which is often considered as "not CentOS", especially, the PHP stack is fully replaced, and standard packages (from CentOS, or any 3rd party repository) can't be installed (excluded in yum configuration).

So you need to add Plesk support (Plesk is a commercial software).

Comment: This community decided some time ago to stop accepting questions about Plesk, cPanel and the like, precisely because of this issue. If you see an old question about them in future, please flag it to be closed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/. It works perfectly on CentOS